# Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to use nginx as my vps web server but I can't get it to work the rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$  modules.php?name=Pages&term=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^Pages.html  modules.php?name=Pages  [L]
```

I have tried these but not working:

```
http://www.anilcetin.com/


set $rule_0 1;
    rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /;
    set $rule_1 1;
    rewrite ^/Pages.html /;

location ^/page {
    try_files /page/index.php?$args =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate those auto converters, they create weird rewrite rules, anyway try this one

```
rewrite ^/page/(.*) /modules.php?name=Pages&term=$1 last;
rewrite ^/Pages.html /modules.php?name=Pages last;
```

Keep in mind that you didn't use the flag `[QSA]` so I didn't append the rest of the `$query_string` to the rerwite, if your code could use something like `/Pages.html?lang=en` for example you need to append the `$query_string`